# How can I type curly braces while using the TTY?

Tags: keyboard-layout, tty

When I'm running on battery, I prefer to use the TTYs instead of the full blown GUI as I can squeeze a *lot* more run time out this way.

However, when I want to type in curly braces (<kbd>AltGr</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>è</kbd> and <kbd>AltGr</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>+</kbd> on my Italian keyboard) the TTY (and *only* that TTY) acts as if I was holding my <kbd>Alt</kbd> key.

I also get this problem for *any* <kbd>AltGr</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd> key combination -- the curly braces are just the most commonly used for me.

Why is that? How can I prevent it?

Here's my output for `stty -a`:

```
speed 38400 baud; rows 48; columns 160; line = 0;
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^?; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = <undef>;
eol2 = <undef>; swtch = <undef>; start = ^Q; stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; rprnt = ^R;
werase = ^W; lnext = ^V; flush = ^O; min = 1; time = 0;
-    parenb -parodd cs8 hupcl -cstopb cread -clocal -crtscts
-ignbrk -brkint -ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr icrnl ixon ixoff
-iuclc -ixany -imaxbel -iutf8
opost -olcuc -ocrnl onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0 ff0
isig icanon -iexten echo echoe echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase -tostop -echoprt
echoctl echoke
```

Answer (score 2):

run

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure console-setup
```

to reconfigure your console-setup. During this process you can specify you keyboard setup including the AltGr setup.

If no confguration options are presented run

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure -plow console-setup
```

instead.

Under `Origin of the keyboard` select the correct layout. For example: the US keyboard doesn't have an AltGr key at all. Whereas the German keyboard does have an AltGr key.

Under `AltGr key replacement:` select the position of the AltGr key. Most likely you want to choose `Right Alt`.

Don't forget to reboot or run `setupcon` on your tty console.

Comment: I did that and set the AltGr key to "Right Alt". This didn't fix the problem, however.

Comment: did you reboot or run setupcon from your tty console? console-setup tells you to do so.

Comment: Yes, I have done so indeed.

Answer (score 0):

My italian layout works out of the box.

You could try `loadkeys it` but if your other keys are working I think that the italian layout is already loaded.

Maybe you have some sort of uncommon keyboard and you need to create your own keymap.

From `dumpkeys` on my italian laptop keyboard I see:

```
shift altgr keycode 26 = braceleft
shift altgr keycode 27 = braceright
```

where **26** is keycode for **egrave** and **27** is **plus**.
You can get your keycodes with `showkey` command.

Comment: The problem is that altgr-shift enables some sort of alt lock on the tty I'm in -- no curly brace is sent to the terminal in the first place.

Comment: Can you post your `stty -a` output?